# Using filter operators (<, >, <=, >=, or) in Directus

Tags: directus

I want to filter with these specific operators:

```
- "<", ">", "<=", ">=" for integer and date values.
- "or" for text fields.
```

PS: my question concerns the admin backend UI not the underlying API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been added in the last major release of Directus (v7)

[image]